# Implement seamless Compute function on SQL Server 2012

Tags: function, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

**Information**: We are in the process of Testing our upgrade from SQL Server 2005 to SQL server 2012 on staging. In reading the documentation on features that will no longer be supported, [COMPUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) going away is going to be an issue for us.

**Question:** Is there any way to write out our own procedure that will take the place of the compute builtin on SQL Server 2012 that will make it seamless so when Compute is called it will function like SQL Server 2005? The alternative is we will we need to update all the SQL files, UDF's, Triggers, and stored procedures that use this built in with alternative code?

**Note** I have never tried to recreate a built in function before so any information on this will be very helpful for me and anyone else trying to do this in the future. Also knowing if it can be done is a plus.

**Clenup:** As always if this is a duplicate post indicate the link below and i will remove my post.

Comment: `COMPUTE BY` is not a function. I don't see how it's effects (generating additional result sets) can be replicated easily. I'm curious: Why did you use COMPUTE BY? It seems to be a hideous API.

Comment: You are correct, it is part of the native syntax in 2005. however it would need to be implemented another way if it could be, hence the use of the word function. I personally think the correct solution would be upgrade to 2008 R2 which will give us a few years to correct all the locations its used and then upgrade to 2012. Compute was used in the legacy code (COBOL and Batch processes that call SQL files) i have replaced it with more efficient code when i have found it used. There is just 20+ years of code to review and i am concerned that to many things will break with the live upgrade.

Comment: I have made the recommendation of moving to SQL Server 2008 first, this will give us 4 years or so to update all the code and then we can move up to SQL Server 2012. I will cleanup this question next week as it is no longer applicable to our issue. On the research i have done it seems as though extending the existing syntax to add this feature back in is not something that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMPUTE BY` is not a function. I don't see how it's effects (generating additional result sets) can be replicated easily.

Replacing COMPUTE BY with a temp table and some looping should be kind of straight forward but it will be a laborious task. It's probably better to change the application so that it does not depend on multiple result sets.

> I have made the recommendation of moving to SQL Server 2008 first, this will give us 4 years or so to update all the code and then we can move up to SQL Server 2012.

That sounds reasonable. By then there will be at least SQL Server 2016 so you'll have to see what other features are deleted at that point :)

Comment: Enjoy the win, thanks for taking the time to mull this over with me!